# Broker Direct Connection

Tags: nat, port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel, forwarding

Is it possible to use a server with a static IP address to broker a direct connection between 2 clients which are each behind NAT's?

I've used autossh and port forwarding to set up a connection *through* the server but I *think* that means any interaction between the clients consumes server resources (computational overhead of forwarding packets & bandwidth).  I can't test for myself because I don't have access to one of the clients at the moment.

**What I imagine happening diagrammatically** (I own A, B, and the server so whichever client connects first can just wait until the other connects):

```
client A -----> server <----- client B
```

I think the reverse tunneling method does this:

```
A sends packet -----> server,
server receives packet,
server sends packet -----> B,
B receives packet
```

and vice versa. What I'd like is:

```
A connects -----> server (connection stays open until B connects)
B connects -----> server (server tells B about A)
A and B can communicate bidirectionally while the connection stays open
```

(if there are disconnects A and B can repeat the connection step)

I think this must be possible (isn't this how P2P protocols work?) but I don't know how to set this up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've used autossh and port forwarding to set up a connection through the server but I think that means any interaction between the clients consumes server resources (computational overhead of forwarding packets & bandwidth).

You are correct

There are two tools by [Samy Kamkar](https://samy.pl/) allowing two hosts behind NAT to communicate with each other, [pwnat](https://samy.pl/pwnat/) and [chownat](https://samy.pl/chownat/). There are descriptions of the trick/technique on the site if you'd like to implement your solution using this method, or otherwise you can use the tools Samy has published.

Broadly, `chownat` is for A<->B communication when both agree that they would like to communicate; and `pwnat` is for A->B communication that B is not expecting. You could use the former if they shared state over the server to agree when to open a `chownat` tunnel; or otherwise use `pwnat` and not need the server at all.